# Unable to return a string from a function

Tags: c, string, linked-list

list.c

```
char *get_value ( node *handle,  char *name) {

    node *current = handle;

    while (current) {
        if((!strcmp(current->name, name)))  {
            printf("=> %s %s %s\n", __func__, current->name, current->value);
            return current->value;
        }
        current=current->next;
    }
    return "";
}

void list_add(node **handle, char *name, char *value)
{   
    node *current, *new;
    new = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (value == NULL) {
        value = "";
    }
    strcpy(new->name, name);
    strcpy(new->value, value);
    new->next = NULL;
    current = *handle;
    if(*handle == NULL) {
        *handle = new;
    }
    else    {
        while(current->next != NULL)    {
            current=current->next;
        }
        current->next = new;
    }

}
```

When calling this function from main.c I was unable to retrieve 
the returning string(current->value) and getting a segmentation 
fault but able to print in the same function.

main.c

```
struct node {
    char name[100]; 
    char value[512];
    struct node *next;
};

node handle = NULL;

int main () {
....
list_add(&handle,"a","1");
printf("%s\n", get_value (handle, name));
....
}
```

Getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: You really don't need the double parentheses in the `if` statement.  You could safely use: `if (!strcmp(current->name, name))` or even `if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0)` (which, IMO, emphasizes better that you're testing the strings for equality).

Comment: Your problem looks to be outside the code you show.  If the structure is initialized appropriately, then you should be safe.  Since you're getting a core dump, I'm deeply suspicious that there's a problem in the way you create the linked list.  However, without an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses),
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)), it is hard to know what's going wrong.

Comment: Yeah I have removed some conditions in if and forgot to remove those parentheses

Comment: I think we need to see how you initialized the list, please display

Comment: I have included the code what I have done

Comment: `node handle = NULL;` did not throw any error?

Comment: You have `void list_add(node **handle, ...` but you are passing a `node *` (`&handle`) as the first argument. That's one clue that there's something wrong with your logic.

Answer (score 1):

1. The list_add function expects (a pointer to) an array of type node (unintended): `void list_add(node **handle, ...` but you are passing a heap pointer of type node from main: `list_add(&handle,"a","1");`
2. Initialisation of `handle` is incomplete: `node handle = NULL;` should be (something like) `node handle = {"","",NULL};`
3. Don't return stack memory (char array) to caller (main): `return "";` is ok because "" is one char ('\0') only, but better to define heap place holder for 'empty' return char array.

Working code:

```
struct node_ {
    char name[100];
    char value[512];
    struct node_ *next;
} typedef node;

//declarations - linked list of type node, not array node** structure
char *get_value(node *handle, char *name);
void list_add(node *handle, char *name, char *value);

//initialise heap variable
node handle = {"","", NULL };
char _notFound__[1] = "";


int main() {

    //passing address of heap variable 'handle' 
    list_add(&handle, "a", "1");

    //passing address of heap variable 'handle'
    printf("%s\n", get_value(&handle, "a"));

    return 0;

}


char *get_value(node *handle, char *name) {

    //asign placeholder
    node *current = handle;

    //search linked list
    while (current) {
        if (!strcmp(current->name, name)) {
            printf("=> %s %s %s\n", __func__, current->name, current->value);

            //return pointer to heap memory
            return current->value;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    //return pointer to heap char-array memory
    return _notFound__;
}

void list_add(node *handle, char *name, char *value)
{
    node *current, *new;

    //heap memory - requires destruction at heap scope
    new = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    //initialise (copy construction)
    (name) ? strcpy(new->name, name) : strcpy(new->name, "");
    (value) ? strcpy(new->value, value) : strcpy(new->value, "");
    new->next = NULL;

    //insert new item
    if (handle == NULL) {
        handle = new;
    }
    else
    {
        //assign placeholder
        current = handle;

        //scroll to end
        while (current->next != NULL) 
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = new;
    }

}
```